# Function in C returns initial value of a variable

Tags: absolute

I just started programming and I have struggle understanding functions with return value. I tried for example to make function that returns the absolute value of a real number:

## include

```
double absol(double x) {

    if (x>0) {
        return (x);
    }
    else {
        return (-x);
    }
}
main() {
    double x;
    scanf("%fl",&x);
    printf("%f",absol(x));
}
```

It give zero back and if I change the initial value of x, it gives this value back. Why doesn't it take the value that I input with scanf?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you verified that `scanf()` is actually returning a non-zero value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf("%fl",&x);` will not correctly read in a double. You need `scanf("%lf",&x);` instead.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Odd that it wasn't reporting an error. It works now.

Comment: @JovJov I believe it didn't give an error because `%fl` is still valid. It describes a float followed by the letter `l`.